# BackgroundWorker not running on separate thread

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading

So, I'm trying to use a BackgroundWorker to fetch some data for me while the user interacts with the window. I'm using BW instead of async/await because the project is made in .NET 4.0, and apparently it has to stay that way.

For some reason, the worker blocks the main thread until it's finished, as the user can't interact with the window until the work is complete.

Here is the code I'm using (removed non-essential parts)

```
 private Dictionary<string, DataSet> estadisticas;
 private Dictionary<string, int> count;

 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    estadisticas = new Dictionary<string, DataSet>();
    count = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
    bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_DoWork);
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}

private void GetData()
{
    foreach (DataRowView row in DEstcli.estadisticas.Tables["tabla_propuesta"].DefaultView)
    {
        if (!estadisticas.ContainsKey(row.Row["CodArt"].ToString())) {
                    var articulo = row.Row["CodArt"].ToString();
                    int counter;
                    var res = new resumen_esta[3];
                    DataSet data = DEstcli.dataset(articulo, almacenes, out counter, res);
                    estadisticas.Add(row.Row["CodArt"].ToString(), data);
                    count.Add(row.Row["CodArt"].ToString(), counter);
                }
    }
}
```

Later Edit: Changing the BackgroundWorker to a thread with Priority.Lowest opens my window, but I can't do anything on it. The datagrids are shown but not to their complete width, the window won't finish its initialization, for some reason, until the thread completes.

Using the debugger, I can see that everything gets executed in the Main thread. If I freeze the Main Thread, it stops fetching the data. I can see that my thread was created with the name I gave it, but it won't work.

Comment: Where does the data come from?

Comment: And where does it go?  What are estadisticas and count ?

Comment: @MarcelTheis the data comes from various SQL selects in the background. They work just fine, but it seems that they run on the main thread

Comment: @HenkHolterman they are both Dictionaries. The first one is String, DataSet; the second is String, int

Comment: this does not seep to be caused by the background worker. Something else must be running on the UI-Thread...

Comment: @Nudity that's why I find it strange, my window is not waiting for those results, as everything dependant on them is initialized to 0, whenever I need to check one of them, if it's prefetched, I display it. If not, I fetch it. However, it won't even let me scroll down or click anywhere on the UI.

Comment: Can you try using `new Thread(() =>{GetData();}).Start();` and see if it changes anything?

Comment: @Nudity seems to be doing the same thing. I actually tried Thread before trying BW, but I was using a dispatcher so I thought it was cause of that. Still locks my window down...

Comment: @ManuAndrei are you working with windows forms or WPF ?

Comment: @Nudity I'm using WPF

Comment: So you start debugging, enter Window_Loaded and your app is frozen ?

Comment: @Nudity apparently, it isn't frozen. Just very, very VERY slow. I can't do anything on it. The thread has Priority.Lowest, doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: How much RAM is used while debugging ?

Comment: I really don't know what else can be the case here. Maybe profiling your application can help. Have a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/. Maybe it puts some light in there

Comment: @Nudity RAM doesn't pass the 100 MB mark. CPU is in the low 20s. Application goes not responding while profiling when it's using the thread. Already put ReSharper on it, waiting for some kind of result, if it stops being Not Responding.

Comment: @Nudity it seems that it prepares the Layout before running the thread, however it prioritizes the thread over calling the Render of the different elements. It still shouldn't influence in any way, the thread should be completely separate and transparent... The only thing I can think of is that maybe, given that it's a lot of data, the garbage collection makes the machine go crazy. Edit: Nevermind, GC is not really high, it only fires 5 or 6 times during the whole execution.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403418/Lifetime-events-of-a-WPF-application according to this ContentRedered is the last event. Maybe try to implement your logic there if you haven't tried that already ...

Comment: @Nudity I'll try that and let you know how it goes; what worries me though is that seeing how it doesn't even allow the content to be rendered, something tells me that it wouldn't let me navigate through the window after it gets rendered. Still going to give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @Nudity took a look at the Thread window in debug. It seems that everything is called from the main thread, for some reason.

Comment: You simplified too much. Not that we want to see your entire program but obviously the error is not in sight here. Start creating a [MCVE] and maybe you can ask a question Or find it yourself.

Comment: To be sure: Running a lengthy op in a Bgw does normally work, without blocking the GUI.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem but be aware that it is possible to use async/await in .Net 4.0 using a nuget package: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2012/10/22/using-asyncawait-without-net-framework-4-5/